# Multiple AJAX Contact form. How to overwrite this code for multiple forms on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have simple one page website. There I have 15 same contact forms with same ID build with simple PHP. My trouble: AJAX is working only with first ID. All other forms open white page with "Thank you".
My code:

```
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

I have only one solution - Make different ID for all contact forms and then target them manually inside JS. But I think this code is not good practice and is not optimized. Please, help to overwrite this code.
I would appreciate any help for this.

Comment: Simple: You cannot use same id on multiple elements in an html page. Use class name and use $('.contact-form')

Comment: Thank you for this comment. But the problem is still actual. AJAX is working only for first class. All other forms opens white window with "Thank you".

Comment: Post your html !!

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique on the page. This is why it's not working.

It's not a good practice to use the same ID for multiple elements. All elements can share a class name instead.

Comment: Yes, I can use multiple ID. But the main problem is with AJAX.